# Centre figure horizontally and vertically

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, alignment

I want to centre my figure under a heading both horizontally and vertically. I have currently done the horizontal centring via \centering and via the optional argument [h] the image appears under the heading. There should be nothing else on the page except the image. The following is a small example of what I mean:

```
\documentclass[final, english]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\section*{Heading}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \draw[->, thick] (0,0) -- (5,0) node[below=0.2] {x};
    \draw[->, thick] (0,0) -- (0,5) node[below left=0.3] {y};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Is there a possibility to adjust the vertical alignment via optional arguments or how could this be set?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can try the float option `[p]` instead of `[h]`.

Comment: Unfortunately the option [p] doesn't work

Comment: try `\vfill` as shown in the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[final, english]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\section*{Heading}
\vfill
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \draw[->, thick] (0,0) -- (5,0) node[below=0.2] {x};
    \draw[->, thick] (0,0) -- (0,5) node[below left=0.3] {y};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\vfill
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works very well!